# how to Map this array to get a calculated sum number of all the summry.worth.value in side each object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```js
[{
  "id": "5f283e239b81681618b19b5d",
  "listItemId": 3,
  "formData": {
    "name": "הבית שלנו בחיפה ",
    "address": "הגולן 150",
    "geo": "ישראל",
    "currency": "NIS",
    "productPrice": "150000",
    "expectedRevenue": "6955"
  },
  "productId": 1,
  "formId": 1,
  "createdAt": "2020-08-03T16:41:07.691Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-08-03T16:42:49.407Z",
  "summary": {
    "appreciationPer": 0,
    "sumYieldPer": 0,
    "portfolioPer": 0.022,
    "worth": {
      "currency": "ILS",
      "value": 150000
    },
    "yieldPer": 0
  }
}, {
  "id": "5f283e499b81681618b19b5e",
  "listItemId": 4,
  "formData": {
    "name": "הבית שלנו בארהבב",
    "address": "רבי מלוביץת 10",
    "geo": "ארהב",
    "currency": "USD",
    "productPrice": "1500000",
    "expectedRevenue": "699"
  },
  "productId": 1,
  "formId": 1,
  "createdAt": "2020-08-03T16:41:45.317Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-08-03T16:41:45.317Z",
  "summary": {
    "appreciationPer": 0,
    "sumYieldPer": 0,
    "portfolioPer": 0.761,
    "worth": {
      "currency": "ILS",
      "value": 5261700
    },
    "yieldPer": 0
  }
}, {
  "id": "5f283e699b81681618b19b5f",
  "listItemId": 5,
  "formData": {
    "name": "דירהב אירופה",
    "address": "אירוהפם 2",
    "geo": "אירופה",
    "currency": "NIS",
    "productPrice": "1500000",
    "expectedRevenue": "6000"
  },
  "productId": 1,
  "formId": 1,
  "createdAt": "2020-08-03T16:42:17.087Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-08-03T16:42:17.087Z",
  "summary": {
    "appreciationPer": 0,
    "sumYieldPer": 0,
    "portfolioPer": 0.761,
    "worth": {
      "currency": "ILS",
      "value": 5261700
    },
    "yieldPer": 0
  }
}]
```

hey, how to Map this array to get a calculated sum of all the summry.worth.value property in side each object...

can someone pls help me figure how to do it?

Comment: could you tell us what you've tried please ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

> The `reduce()` method executes a **reducer** function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in single output value.

---

```
var total = array.reduce((accumulator, current_value)=> {
    return accumulator + current_value.summary.worth.value;
}, 0);
```

Example:

```js
var array = [{
    "id": "5f283e239b81681618b19b5d",
    "listItemId": 3,
    "formData": {
      "name": "הבית שלנו בחיפה ",
      "address": "הגולן 150",
      "geo": "ישראל",
      "currency": "NIS",
      "productPrice": "150000",
      "expectedRevenue": "6955"

    },
    "productId": 1,
    "formId": 1,
    "createdAt": "2020-08-03T16:41:07.691Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-08-03T16:42:49.407Z",
    "summary": {
      "appreciationPer": 0,
      "sumYieldPer": 0,
      "portfolioPer": 0.022,
      "worth": {
        "currency": "ILS",
        "value": 150000

      },
      "yieldPer": 0

    }

  },
  {
    "id": "5f283e499b81681618b19b5e",
    "listItemId": 4,
    "formData": {
      "name": "הבית שלנו בארהבב",
      "address": "רבי מלוביץת 10",
      "geo": "ארהב",
      "currency": "USD",
      "productPrice": "1500000",
      "expectedRevenue": "699"

    },
    "productId": 1,
    "formId": 1,
    "createdAt": "2020-08-03T16:41:45.317Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-08-03T16:41:45.317Z",
    "summary": {
      "appreciationPer": 0,
      "sumYieldPer": 0,
      "portfolioPer": 0.761,
      "worth": {
        "currency": "ILS",
        "value": 5261700

      },
      "yieldPer": 0

    }

  },
  {
    "id": "5f283e699b81681618b19b5f",
    "listItemId": 5,
    "formData": {
      "name": "דירהב אירופה",
      "address": "אירוהפם 2",
      "geo": "אירופה",
      "currency": "NIS",
      "productPrice": "1500000",
      "expectedRevenue": "6000"

    },
    "productId": 1,
    "formId": 1,
    "createdAt": "2020-08-03T16:42:17.087Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-08-03T16:42:17.087Z",
    "summary": {
      "appreciationPer": 0,
      "sumYieldPer": 0,
      "portfolioPer": 0.761,
      "worth": {
        "currency": "ILS",
        "value": 5261700

      },
      "yieldPer": 0

    }

  }
];

var total = array.reduce((accumulator, current)=> accumulator+current.summary.worth.value, 0);

console.log(total);
```